# Is hard panning the best practise when double tracking?

Tags: audio-recording, mixing

Apart from stereo width, why do people hard pan Left and Right when doing double tracking? Why not 50L & 50R or somewhere between? Is it because of phase cancellation?

Comment: What's the context? Stereo recording? Field recording with boom/lavalier?

Comment: Just recording two times for the same part (a mono guitar track).

Comment: ah ok I understand now. see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think hard panning as opposed to 50%L/R is just personal preference - nothing to do with phase cancellation.

Obviously with hard L/R you will get a wider stereo sound-stage - I think it just depends on what you want in the mix. You can also try and introduce some chorus and delay to give you even more depth to the sound.